# How can I add the multiplication sign to an algebraic expression through regex?

Tags: regex

I am writing a mathematical parser in which a user can enter answers to be evaluated. How can I convert something like `'xe^x + xyz'` to `'x*e^x + x*y*z'` through Regex?

Alternative methods would be welcome too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for each occurrence of:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

Replace by:

```
*
```

---

***Edit:***

As pointed out by *@ChristopherCreutzig*, this regex will also handle the cases like `23xy` in the **most probable expected way**. That is:

- considering a **sequence of digits** as a part of a **single expressoin**,
- considering a **digit followed by a letter** as a **multiplication**,
- considering a **letter followed by a digit** as part of a **single expression**.

For example, for this input:

```
2x1 + 3xy
```

The resulting output is:

```
2*x1 + 3*x*y
```

See it in action and try it out live [here on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/mK2vH6).

Comment: Works great. This finally helped me understand how to implement regex. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that this only works for 2 variables. How could I make it work for n variables? For example, rendering `abcd` as `a*b*c*d`.

Comment: You're right! Try out the new version of the regex I'm suggesting in my edited answer ;)

Comment: Extending the question, I’d suggest `(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])` to also handle `23x` in the most probably appropriate way.

Comment: That's a good point! Thank you. I'm editing my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\w)(?=\w)
```

(looking one letter before and after)

replace by

```
*
```